# django cache not working as expected

Tags: django, memcached, django-cache

I'd like to add simple cache functionality to my site. I have enabled cache for anonymous users, but it does not work as expected. I'm using memcached.
settings.py

```
########################### caching #################################
CACHE_PORT = '11211'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 60
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = "default"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True

# Production Environment
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '%s:%s' % (os.environ['OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP'], CACHE_PORT),
        }
    }

    CACHE_VIEW_LENGTH = datetime.now() + timedelta(30) # 30 day cache expiration

# Development Environment
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:%s' % CACHE_PORT,
        }
    }

    CACHE_VIEW_LENGTH = datetime.now() + timedelta(1) # Set to 0 for development
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #cache  - must be first in middleware_classes
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    #cache end
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #cache  - must be last in middleware_classes
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    #cache end

)
```

Since I have set `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True`, I would except that if I load page as logged in user, I would not get cached version.
I loaded index page where is list of my objects. There are 10 objects. I added new object through form. When I checked on my index page again, I see only 10 objects.
So my question is simple: **Why is django ignoring my setting for anonymous only and caches pages for logged in users**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` option was removed in Django 1.8. Here is the ticket about that: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15201

When `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` was working, it was only about **writing** to cache. When `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` is True, non-anonymous request never writes to cache, but reads from cache.